# SharePoint Online - "add a page" missing from cog menu

Tags: sharepoint-online

6 hours ago the cog menu in our Australia hosted SharePoint online tenant had the "add a page" option. Now the "add a page" menu item is missing from the cog menu.

Does anyone know if this is by design or a mistake ?
Is it just my tenant or is this occurring in other tenants ?

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have enabled the publishing features